# Is there any way to add source code browsing for referenced libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I had been working with Java in IntelliJ IDEA (which I love) for the past few months and I kind of got used to adding the source code of the external libraries I was using in the IDE so that I could browse through it. I found this to be the best documentation most of the times since when I wanted to know what a method did I could just click on it, "Go To Implementation". Maybe I'm just too curious.

I'm back to working in C# in Visual Studio and I'm kind of missing that kind of stuff. I am working with some open source libraries with which I would like to be able to do something similar as in IntelliJ. Of course I could just add the code in the solution, but I guess that would mean I would compile it with the rest of my code every time and I'm not interested in that.

This is mostly useful for me for libraries for which there is not much documentation available.

I was looking for how to do this in Visual Studio and had no luck so far.

Has anybody been interested in something like this before and solved it ? Maybe I just have the wrong approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, large portions of the source code of the .NET Framework are available as the Reference Source.  Search MSFT for this, basic troubleshooting help is available in [this page](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/troubleshooting.aspx).  Access to the unpublished parts is available through Redgate's [Reflector Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) product.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the Frameworks code. I guess the solution would be reflector, but I just don't like the idea of  having to pay for it to decompile source code I already have (since the libraries are open source).

Comment: I doubt that libraries that you have to decompile are open source.  No need to decompile anything if you have the source, just build it so you get the .pdbs (debug info files).  In case they don't already are included.

Comment: True, but for $100, that's a great value.

Comment: @Hans: That's true, I hadn't thought of that. Then you just reference them in your project and you should be golden to step in while debugging, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the .pdb location is embedded in the DLL.  As long as you don't move anything you'll have no trouble browsing the source.  You can also set a Solution property to give the path to the source code files.

Comment: Actually they are open source, I don't really need to decompile anything, I have the source, I just want simple browsing through it during coding not while debugging by "go to implementation", etc. Examples: Nhibernate, FluentMigrator, Json .NET, etc... Does the solution you propose allow for that ?

Comment: @Hans: Ok. What is the solution property called? I can't find it.

Comment: "Debug Source Files", hard to miss.  The .pdb is still needed, this setting only helps if the DLL was built with the source code files on another drive or directory.

Comment: @Hans: Ah. I was looking under project properties, not solution properties. @Lilitu88: Yes, just compile them with the debug build configuration (so you get theh pdb's and reference the assemblies in your project. You should them be able to step into them while debugging no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is use Reflector to see the source code in your language of choice. . .

By the way, it looks like with the Pro version, you can actually step into the assemblies code when debugging.

[Wikipedia - .NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector)

[Reflector Home Page](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)